# Find Range in which value lies in Java

Tags: java, collections

Suppose, I have an unsorted array of ranges.
For e.g

```
class CreditRange{
   long credits;
   int id;
}
```

Now I want to find, given credit count value belongs to which one of the CreditRange.

Possible `Set<CreditRange>` of values can be

```
CreditRange :{id:1,credits:0}
CreditRange :{id:2,credits:100}
CreditRange :{id:3,credits:500}
CreditRange :{id:4,credits:250}
```

> Case 1 : Now when user enters Credits = 50, this range comparator should give
>   answer as

`CreditRange :{id:1,credits:0}`

> Case 2 : Now when user enters Credits = 300, this range comparator should give
>   answer as

`CreditRange :{id:4,credits:250}`

> Case 3 : Now when user enters Credits = 600, this range comparator should give
>   answer as

`CreditRange :{id:3,credits:500}`

We can assume the ranges array takes ~1M and fits the memory. I am looking for an easy algorithm, which uses only standard JDK collections without any 3d-party libraries and special data structures, but works reasonably fast.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Is it an array or a set?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's a Set of CreditRange

Comment: I fail to see how `CreditRange` is actually a *range* at all. It only has a single bound. If you want it to be a real range, you need it to have both upper and lower bounds. If you want to keep the current structure, you should rename it to something like `CreditBound`, make sure that you have it as an *ordered* collection (probably not a set) and then use a binary chop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess, it's not the range you are talking about. Rather you want the largest element that is less than your passed element.

You can follow the below steps to solve the problem:

- First implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your class, which compares on the basis of *credits*
- Then, use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), passing an instance of that comparator to it's constructor. It will sort the item inside it, as per the comparator.
- Then use [`TreeSet#floor(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor%28E%29) method to get the greatest element which is less than `E`, as per the comparator. Of course, you have to create an object of `CreditRange` to search. You can't just search for `300`.

**Demo code:**

```
NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.add(0);   set.add(100);
set.add(250); set.add(500);

System.out.println(set.floor(50));  // 0
System.out.println(set.floor(300)); // 250
```

And please rename your class. It is not depicting the range in any manner. It should perhaps be better named as `CreditBound` as specified by Jon Skeet in comments.

Comment: Although that would require creating a `CreditRange` object to find the value, which is a bit unfortunate :(

Comment: @JonSkeet. Yes. I wish Java had this feature of finding the object based on it's element. :( It would have been a great relief.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Rohit, one easy method is to use TreeSet floor (another is to implement a a modified variant of Binary search. this is a more complete answer:

```
package test;

import java.util.TreeSet;

class CreditRange implements Comparable<CreditRange> {
  long credits;
  int id;

  public CreditRange(int id, long credits) {
    this.id = id;
    this.credits = credits;
  }

  public CreditRange(long credits) {
    this.id = -1;
    this.credits = credits;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(CreditRange o) {
    return credits < o.credits ? -1 : credits > o.credits ? 1 : 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "id:" + id + ", credits:" + credits;
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<CreditRange> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.add(new CreditRange(1, 0));
    set.add(new CreditRange(2, 100));
    set.add(new CreditRange(3, 500));
    set.add(new CreditRange(4, 250));
    System.out.println(set.floor(new CreditRange(50)));
    System.out.println(set.floor(new CreditRange(300)));
    System.out.println(set.floor(new CreditRange(600)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure this is a complete answer, but I wanted OP to figure this out. That is why I didn't posted the code. You have given OP a plain copy-paste recipe.

Comment: well, when I first saw your answer you didn't have the demo code and the explanation of the missing parts and how to implement them, so I went ahead and created this (also gave the binary search a stab, which is why it took some time).
now that it's here, I don't see a point in removing it.

Comment: No issues. Of course I'm forcing you to do it. Don't take it otherwise. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But i have already implemented it using @RohitJain approach.